# NSFilemanager doesn't create file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I have a problem with NSFileManager, because i only can store a file into Application Documents Directory, but i want to create a file into a sub directory this i don't think why, i couldn't create. my code below:

```
+(NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}

+(BOOL)storeFile:(NSData*)file withName:(NSString*)name atDirectory:(NSString*)dir{

    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSString *newDir;
    BOOL create=NO;
    filemgr =[NSFileManager defaultManager];


    docsDir = [StorageManager applicationDocumentsDirectory];

    newDir = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:dir];

    if(![filemgr fileExistsAtPath:newDir]){
        if([filemgr createDirectoryAtPath:newDir withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil  error:nil]){
            create=YES;
        }    
    }else
        create=YES;

    if(create){
        if(![filemgr createFileAtPath:newDir contents:file attributes:nil]){
            [filemgr release];
            return YES;
        }
    }

        [filemgr release];
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why the file is not created. At first glance, it looks like your code should work. But I may be overlooking something. It also depends on what exactly you are passing as arguments to the `storeFile:withName:atDirectory:` method.

Nevertheless I am posting an answer because I did spot another error in your code: you should *not* send `release` to `filemgr` since you also did not send `retain` to it first and you did *not* create the object. In this case, there is no need to send `retain` to it either, since you are only using it locally within your method. You may want to review the Apple Developer Connection document "[Cocoa Core Competencies: Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html)".

I don't think this error explains why the file is not created; though I'm surprised your application doesn't crash because of it.

Comment: if i don't create the folder and try to create the same file but inside the documents folder it happens well.. i think i have to set permissions to the newfolder...

Comment: Hi, thanks for help i just find the solution!!! The problem is i didn't append to the file path the file name... omg this problem is solved...